# Prevent a modal to close after submitting a form bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have already seen other questions but doesn't have anything similar to my question:

I am using bootstrap 4 and I am trying to prevent my modal to close.

Here is what I am trying to do:

**index.php:**

I have a button called View button in that I am calling anotherfile.PHP file inside a modal.

Modal is open and anotherfile.php is showing up properly.

**anotherfile.php** has the following:

A simple text box with a submit button and some calculation inside POST in the same PHP file.

So when I click the submit button modal gets closed. I am looking for a way to refresh and results have to come up within the modal.

Here is my anotherfile.php code

```
 <?php
    include ('db\config.php');
    global $conn;
    
    if(!empty($_POST)){
      //some calculation is done using the ID posted from the form.
    }
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Get Data</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Download Data</h2>
       <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <form action="" Method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="pwd">ID:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" placeholder="Enter ID" name="id" required>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Download</button>
                <a href="detail.php" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-block">Go Back</a>
              </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    </body>
```

Everywhere the form is placed inside the modal. Over here I am placing a PHP file inside the modal. It is totally different. Please don't close it with duplicate question.

Comment: Are you saving results to a database or anything where a POST request would be required? If not, you can set an event listener on the submit button, then do e.preventDefault(). This will prevent the form from submitting. You can then do your calculations, then update the form components accordingly by setting their value property in JavaScript. AJAX may be another option for you as well.

Comment: I am submitting a POST request and get values from DB according to values posted the only problem is that the page is getting refreshed and because of that the modal is getting closed.

Comment: Check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Set a click event listener on the button, use e.preventDefault() to prevent the request from being posted on the form, then use Fetch to submit a post request and await response, then update modal accordingly.

Comment: How are you calling anotherfile.php inside the modal? Are you using an iframe?